# Performance of numerical integral over piecewise function

Tags: numerical-integration, piecewise

Using mathematica version 10.3, I observe that an integral over a piecewise function evaluates a factor 10 slower than the same integral without the piecewise distinction. Here is the code:

Originally, I have defined the function `g1` and the integral over `g1`, `fs`, as

```
Kaold[k_] := EllipticK[k^2/(-1 + k^2)]/Sqrt[1 - k^2]
kold[p_, y_, z_] := Sqrt[4 y z/(p^2 + (y + z)^2)]
g1old[x_, y_] := 
 1/Pi Sqrt[1/(
   x y)] (kold[0, x, y] Kaold[kold[0, x, y]] - 
    kold[1, x, y] Kaold[kold[1, x, y]])
fsold[r_, r0_, d_] := NIntegrate[x g1old[x d, r d], {x, 0, 20}]
```

However, `g1` in this definition has issues with floating point precision when `x-y` becomes small. Therefore, I developed an alternative representation

```
Ka[k_] := EllipticK[k^2/(-1 + k^2)]/Sqrt[1 - k^2]
Kaomks[x_] := EllipticK[(x - 1)/x]/Sqrt[x]
k0[z_] := Sqrt[(4 z)/(1 + z)^2]
k1[y_, z_] := Sqrt[(4 y z)/(1 + (y + z)^2)]
omks[p_, y_, z_] := (p^2 + (y - z)^2)/(p^2 + (y + z)^2)
g1[x_, y_] := \[Piecewise] {
   {1/Pi Sqrt[1/(
      x y)] (k0[x/y] Kaomks[omks[0, x, y]] - 
       k1[x, y] Kaomks[omks[1, x, y]]), k0[x/y] > 0.5},
   {1/Pi Sqrt[1/(x y)] (k0[x/y] Ka[k0[x/y]] - k1[x, y] Ka[k1[x, y]]), 
    True}
  }
fs[r_, r0_, d_] := NIntegrate[x g1[x d, r d], {x, 0, 20}]
```

Both functions yield the same result, if evaluated with sufficient precision. The second version is much more robust against finite numerical precision. However, unfortunately, the integral `fs` of the second approach evaluated much slower than in the initial representation. On my PC,

```
fs[25., 25., 0.01] // Timing
```

takes 0.14 seconds and

```
fsold[25., 25., 0.01] // Timing
```

takes 0.01 seconds. I believe that this is due to the piecewise distinction in the function `g1` because if I choose only one of the piecewise cases

```
g2[x_, y_] := 
 1/Pi Sqrt[1/(
   x y)] (k0[x/y] Kaomks[omks[0, x, y]] - 
    k1[x, y] Kaomks[omks[1, x, y]])
fs2[r_, r0_, d_] := NIntegrate[x g2[x d, r d], {x, 0, 20}]
g3[x_, y_] := 
 1/Pi Sqrt[1/(x y)] (k0[x/y] Ka[k0[x/y]] - k1[x, y] Ka[k1[x, y]])
fs3[r_, r0_, d_] := NIntegrate[x g3[x d, r d], {x, 0, 20}]
```

then both `fs2` and `fs3` evaluate within 0.01 seconds (and yield the same result).

How can I improve the performance of the piecewise function? I would like to avoid splitting `fs` in two separate integrals, where each integral contains only one of the two representations of `g1`, because I am trying to evaluate `fs` with a given precision goal and that is much easier if it is only one term.

Comment: Unable to test right now, but does adding `Method->{Automatic,“SymbolicProcessing“->0}`  to your `NIntegrate` speed things up?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you! If you post this as a reply, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that by far most time is spent on symbolic precomputations during `NIntegrate`. You can avoid this by calling the `NIntegrate`command with the option `Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}`.

```
fs[25., 25., 0.01] // AbsoluteTiming
fsold[25., 25., 0.01] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0., 695.762} *)
(* {0., 695.762} *)
```